# C# PhantomJSDriver with Fiddler proxy and HTTP authentication: traffic not captured

Tags: c#, authentication, selenium, phantomjs, fiddlercore

I am trying to navigate to an application on a localhost site that requires authentication using PhantomJSDriver and passing username:password into the URL. In order to capture response codes I'm using a Fiddler proxy from Jim Evan's example https://github.com/jimevans/WebDriverProxyExamples.

PhantomJSDriver navigates successfully (using NTLM/Basic auth) but **Fiddler doesn't capture the traffic.**

```
public static int NavigateTo(this IWebDriver driver, string targetUrl, TimeSpan timeout, bool printDebugInfo)
{
    int responseCode = 0;
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.Add(timeout);
    SessionStateHandler responseHandler = delegate(Session targetSession)
    {
        if (targetSession.responseCode >= 300 && targetSession.responseCode < 400)
        {
            targetUrl = targetSession.GetRedirectTargetURL();
        }
        else
            responseCode = targetSession.responseCode;
    };

    // Attach the event handler, perform the navigation, and wait for
    // the status code to be non-zero, or to timeout. Then detach the
    // event handler and return the response code.
    FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += responseHandler;
    driver.Url = targetUrl;
    while (responseCode == 0 && DateTime.Now < endTime)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete -= responseHandler;
    return responseCode;
}
```

I was able to capture the traffic when using ChromeDriver with the same application and also for a website that didn't require authentication using PhanotmJSDriver. The only scenario it doesn't work in is PhantomJSDriver + authentication website.

**Update:**
I discovered the issue thanks to **Dead Link**
<strike>http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost/</strike>. It was nothing to do with authentication rather getting traffic from localhost.

The solution was to use the local machine name in place of localhost in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue thanks to http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/observe-traffic/troubleshooting/notraffictolocalhost/. It was nothing to do with authentication rather getting traffic from localhost. I'm not sure why, but it seems the combination of using PhantomJSDriver to navigate to a localhost url and Fiddler to capture the traffic did not work.

The solution was to use the local MACHINE NAME in place of 'localhost' in the URL.

Comment: There's no particular reason that Localhost traffic shouldn't be getting captured, unless the PhantomJS script failed to set the proxy bypass list properly. Where in your code do you set the proxy for the PhantomJS process?

Comment: I set the proxy the same way as was done in this example: https://github.com/jimevans/WebDriverProxyExamples/tree/master/HttpStatusCodeExample. I create an OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy and set proxy.HttpProxy = "127.0.0.1:<fiddlerProxyPort>", create a PhantomJSDriverService service and set ProxyType = "http" and Proxy = proxy.HttpProxy. I then create the PhantomJSDriver using the service.